# mysql query doesnot work

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my mysql query!

```
SELECT projects.projects_id, 
       projects.projects_title,
       projects.projects_cost
  FROM projects
       LEFT JOIN invoice
           ON invoice.projects_id = projects.projects_id
       LEFT JOIN project_assign
           ON project_assign.projects_id=projects.projects_id
 WHERE project_assign.assigned_user_id=3 
       AND (SUM( invoice.invoice_amount) < projects.projects_cost 
            OR invoice.projects_id is null )
       AND project_assign.project_completed_date IS NOT NULL
```

In this query i want select all row that:

> 1. Is not present in other table  e.g. (in my case other table is
>      "invoice")
> 2. Or if persent then this condition must hold `sum(invoice.invoice_amount) < projects.projects_cost`

Thanks.

Comment: So what is the issue. Do you get an error, do you not get the results you wanted. What do your table layouts look like, can you provide some dummy data. All these things will help us understand what it currently a very vague question.

Comment: whats the `sum( invoice.invoice_amount)` doing?

Comment: I get this error  "SQL error (1111) invalid use of group function"

Comment: Because the value may be NULL, your query may not be able to handle it. I'm also missing a 'GROUP BY' that would cause the SUM() to give a correct output.

Comment: I use group by statement but does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide your problem. Use a `UNION`. First use one query to select all records that are not present in the first table (Use a LEFT JOIN), union that with the result of your second query which would give you all records meeting your second condition (use an outer join)

```
//Select all records present in left table
//union
//select all records present in both tables matching your condition.

    SELECT projects.projects_id, 
       projects.projects_title,
       projects.projects_cost
  FROM projects
       LEFT JOIN invoice
           ON invoice.projects_id = projects.projects_id
       LEFT JOIN project_assign
           ON project_assign.projects_id=projects.projects_id
  WHERE project_assign.assigned_user_id=3  
  AND project_assign.project_completed_date IS NOT NULL 
    UNION
   SELECT projects.projects_id, 
       projects.projects_title,
       projects.projects_cost
  FROM projects
       INNER JOIN invoice
           ON invoice.projects_id = projects.projects_id
       INNER JOIN project_assign
           ON project_assign.projects_id=projects.projects_id
  WHERE project_assign.assigned_user_id=3 
   AND (SUM( invoice.invoice_amount) < projects.projects_cost  
  AND project_assign.project_completed_date IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select projects.projects_id, projects.projects_title,projects.projects_cost
 from projects
left join invoice
on invoice.projects_id = projects.projects_id
left join project_assign
on project_assign.projects_id=projects.projects_id
where project_assign.assigned_user_id=3 and
 ((select sum(invoice.invoice_amount) from invoice) < projects.projects_cost or invoice.projects_id is null )
and project_assign.project_completed_date is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put aggregation functions in the `where` clause.  In this case, you can do the aggregation using a subquery and then do the comparison:

```
SELECT p.projects_id, p.projects_title, p.projects_cost
FROM projects p LEFT JOIN
     (select i.projects_id, sum(invoice_amount) as invoice_amount
      from invoice i
     ) i
     ON i.projects_id = p.projects_id LEFT JOIN
     project_assign pa
     ON pa.projects_id = p.projects_id
 WHERE pa.assigned_user_id = 3 AND
       (i.invoice_amount < p.projects_cost OR i.projects_id is null ) AND
       pa.project_completed_date IS NOT NULL;
```